# Check if java object exists in the Set

Tags: java, set, java-8

I have a `Set` and I will check if an `Object` with the same property still exists. My first approach was to iterate over the list and check but I guess there is a better approach in Java 8. Does anyone have any suggestion how to check this in an elegant way?

```
final Set<UserSelected> preparedUserSelected = new HashSet<>();

    UserSelected userSelected1 = new UserSelected();
    userSelected1.setInstitutionId("1");
    userSelected1.setUserId("1");
    userSelected1.setChatMessageFilter(ChatMessageFilterEnum.TYP2);

    UserSelected userSelected2 = new UserSelected();
    userSelected2.setInstitutionId("2");
    userSelected2.setUserId("2");
    userSelected2.setChatMessageFilter(ChatMessageFilterEnum.TYP1);

    UserSelected userSelected3 = new UserSelected();
    userSelected3.setInstitutionId("3");
    userSelected3.setUserId("3");
    userSelected3.setChatMessageFilter(ChatMessageFilterEnum.TYP2);

    preparedUserSelected.add(userSelected1);
    preparedUserSelected.add(userSelected2);
    preparedUserSelected.add(userSelected3);

    UserSelected userSelectedToCheck = new UserSelected();
    userSelectedToCheck.setInstitutionId("2");
    userSelectedToCheck.setUserId("2");
    userSelectedToCheck.setChatMessageFilter(ChatMessageFilterEnum.TYP1);

    boolean contains = false;
    for (final UserSelected userSelected : preparedUserSelected) {
        if (userSelectedToCheck.getInstitutionId().equals(userSelected.getInstitutionId())
            && userSelectedToCheck.getUserId().equals(userSelected.getUserId())
            && userSelectedToCheck.getChatMessageFilter() == userSelected.getChatMessageFilter())
            contains = true;
    }

    System.out.println("contains: " + contains);
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `contains` method? Containment checking is what sets *do*. It's their core capability, on top of which everything else they're useful for is built.

Comment: @user2357112 he has specified Java 8 way, I too was confused

Comment: @VedantKekan, OP did not ask about Java Stream API solution, he just asked about some better Java-8 approach, thus java-stream tag is not applicable here.

Comment: @TagirValeev agreed , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [anyMatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) of Lambda Expression(Java 8).

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate. May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

```
boolean isExist = preparedUserSelected.stream()
            .anyMatch(userSelected -> userSelected.getInstitutionId().equalsuserSelected.getInstitutionId());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to properly implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `UserSelected` class. After that you can easily check the existence with `preparedUserSelected.contains(userSelectedToCheck)`.

Here's sample implementation of `equals/hashCode` for your class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getUserId(), getInstitutionId(), getChatMessageFilter());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    UserSelected other = (UserSelected) obj;
    return Objects.equals(getChatMessageFilter(), other.getChatMessageFilter()) &&
            Objects.equals(getInstitutionId(), other.getInstitutionId()) &&
            Objects.equals(getChatMessageFilter(), other.getChatMessageFilter());
}
```